# php database myisam password encryption

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I am setting up a database in MyISAM format. I need to create a login form and since I am new to PHP, I do not know how to encrypt the Column "Password" in the table "Users". Can someone help me with a short and concise tutorial please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the database storage engine does not matter, but you can use MD5.

For more information please have a look.

https://www.php.net/md5

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Thank you Amit.. really helped me out